# How can I print a field on my template?

Tags: 7, theming

How can I print a field on my template, not only in node page but in every page.

I use this in my page.tpl but it's wrong:

```
echo $node->field_custom['und'][0]['value'];
```

---

Update

I solved using this code on template.php:

```
function MyTheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $mynode = node_load(1);
  $vars['field_custom'] = field_get_items('node', $mynode, 'field_custom');
}
```

And this in page.tpl:

```
<?php if (isset($field_custom)) : print $field_custom[0]['value']; endif; ?>
```

Comment: What does "it's wrong" mean?

Comment: The code doesn't work.

Comment: Are you really not going to try to elaborate? That's all you're prepared to offer in terms of a good question for this repository?

Comment: I'll close this until you've had a chance to get it up to scratch. See the [help] for suggestions, or feel free to open a meta question if you don't understand why "it's wrong" and "doesn't work" aren't acceptable problem statements

Comment: I've tried some solution but I haven't really figured how to take the filed of single node and print it on my theme.
I had to write all the code tried so far?

Comment: Not all the code necessarily, no. But definitely some context, yes, and the results of your own debugging efforts are critical here. We can't know, for example, if you've confirmed that the $node variable is or isn't the right object (unless your site is doing something specific, it should be), whether a field with that name even exists, whether the node in question has data for that field, etc, etc. You're asking people to make too many assumptions

Comment: Okay, I get it. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46732/discussion-between-daniele-and-clive).

Comment: @Daniele, FYI: you can take the edit snippet you added and post it as an answer. You're encouraged to answer your questions and mark it as such for future readers benefit.

Comment: @ShawnConn sorry but I can't post an answer for my answer... The post is [on hold]

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
 <?php
    function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      $vars['field_custom'] = '';
      // Get the object and do some other checks based on what you need.
      if (($node = menu_get_object()) && $node->type) {
        // Generate a render array for the node.
        $view = node_view($node);
        // "Create" a new variable for the page.tpl.php.
        // This will expose $VAR_NAME in the page template.
        $vars['field_custom'] = drupal_render($view['field_custom']);
      }
    }
    ?>
```

or you can also use:

```
$vars['field_custom'] = field_get_items('node', $mynode, 'field_custom');
```

Then add this to your page.tpl.php:

```
<?php if (isset($field_custom)) : print $field_custom; endif; ?>
```

Comment: $node is available in the page.tpl.php only if there is some node associated with the page. Check the [variables available in page template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7.x).
Also, node ID will be the second parameter (node/nid)
Then you can access using the `field_get_items`, for example `field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');`

Comment: This is good. But print the render field just in the node page.